# A better way to display a webpage using object tag in another html without using jquery, just plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dashboard in which i want to change only a section of the page when the appropriate button is clicked. Though this code works, it looks to crude, i tried using some regex, but it seems object tag has some restrictions as it fails. Javascript code below

```
// This handles the initial dashboard navigation and changes the main id with only the called page
function dashboard(id) {
     main = document.getElementById('main');
switch(id) {
    case 'newMail':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/sendMail.html"></object>';

    case 'inbox':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/inboxList.html"></object>';

    case 'sent':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/sentList.html"></object>';

    case 'draft':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/draftList.html"></object>';

    case 'deleted':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/deletedList.html"></object>';

    case 'retracted':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/retractedList.html"></object>';

    case 'createGroup':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/createGroup.html"></object>';

    case 'groupList':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/groupList.html"></object>';

    case 'groupMessage':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/groupMessage.html"></object>';

    case 'profile':
        return main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/profile.html"></object>';

    default:
        return document;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use and XHR request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to get the HTML, then use `XMLHttpRequest.response` as the `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object indexed by your `case`s, whose values are the appropriate string that comes right before the `.html`. For example:

```
const pageNamesById = {
  newMail: 'sendMail',
  inbox: 'inboxList',
  sent: 'sentList',
  draft: 'draftList',
  deleted: 'deletedList',
  retracted: 'retractedList',
  createGroup: 'createGroup',
  // etc
};
function dashbord(id) {
  const main = document.getElementById('main');
  const pageName = pageNamesById[id];
  if (pageName) {
    main.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/' + pageName + '.html"></object>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about like this? Common grouped.

```js
const template = (action) => `<object type="text/html" data="file:///home/tochie/andela_challenge/UI/html/dashboard/${action}.html"></object>`;

// This handles the initial dashboard navigation and changes the main id with only the called page
function dashboard(id) {
  main = document.getElementById('main');
  switch (id) {
    case 'newMail':
      return main.innerHTML = template("sendMail");
    case 'inbox':
    case 'sent':
    case 'draft':
    case 'deleted':
    case 'groupList':
    case 'retracted':
      return main.innerHTML = template(`${id}List`);
    case 'createGroup':
    case 'groupMessage':
    case 'profile':
      return main.innerHTML = template(id);
    default:
      return document;
  }
}

console.log(dashboard('newMail'));
console.log(dashboard('inbox'));
console.log(dashboard('deleted'));
console.log(dashboard('groupMessage'));
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```